# Remote clean up

Tags: updates

I heard of " PCmatic.com " that will improve your computer online, and others like this. Is such a thing possible and does Ubuntu have anything to do such a operation to a computer like mine via the web?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you'd ever want to use such a product is to fix the inherent flaws in Windows which you've already fixed by dumping Windows for Linux.

Even if you were running Windows, who are these people? How can you tell that their software isn't an example of the very malware you're trying to avoid?